# Fastest way to find multiple entries from json using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON that has around 50k items where each has an id and name as follows (I cut the data):

```
[
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Cannonball"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Cannon base"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Cannon stand"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Cannon barrels"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Cannon furnace"
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "name": "Insect repellent"
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "name": "Bucket of wax"
    }]
```

Now, I have an array of item names and I want to find the corresponding id and to add it into an id array.

For example, I have `itemName = ['Cannonball', 'Cannon furnace', 'Bucket of wax]`

I would like to search inside the JSON and to return `id_array = [2, 12, 30]`

I wrote the following code which does the work however it seems like a huge waste of energy:

```
file_name = "database.json"
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    document =  json.loads(f.read())

items = ['Cannonball', 'Cannon furnace','Bucket of wax']
for item_name in items:
    for entry in document:
            if item_name == entry ['name']:
                id_array.append(entry ['id'])
```

Is there any faster method that can do it?

The example above shows only 3 results but I'm talking about a few thousand and it feels like a waste to iterate over 1k+ results.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a `lookup` dictionary mapping names to ids and then *look up* the names on that dictionary:

```
lookup = { d["name"] : d["id"] for d in document}

items = ['Cannonball', 'Cannon furnace','Bucket of wax']

result = [lookup[item] for item in items]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 12, 30]
```

The time complexity of this approach is `O(n + m)` where `n` is the number of elements in the document (`len(document)`) and `m` is the number of items (`len(items)`), in contrast your approach is `O(nm)`.

An alternative approach that uses less space, is to filter out those names that are not in items:

```
items = ['Cannonball', 'Cannon furnace', 'Bucket of wax']
item_set = set(items)

lookup = {d["name"]: d["id"] for d in document if d["name"] in item_set}
result = [lookup[item] for item in items]
```

This approach has the same time complexity as the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a `dict` which maps `name` to `id` first:

```py
file_name = "database.json"
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    document =  json.loads(f.read())

name_to_id = {item["name"]:item["id"] for item in document}
```

Now you can just iterate over `items`:

```py
items = ['Cannonball', 'Cannon furnace','Bucket of wax']
id_array = [ name_to_id[name] for name in items]
```